# Calculate Cosine similarity without matrix with duplicate sum from coo_matrix to csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate cosine similarity between products of a purchases dataset.  I have more than 100000 rows ( row = user purchase event) and more than 80000 products.

To avoid using `pandas.crosstab` to make the dataset in the format:

```
>  user_id\item_id  1  2  3  4  ...   
>       1         | 1  1  0  0
>       2         | 0  1  0  0
>       3         | 1  0  1  0
>       4         | 0  0  0  0
>       5         | 0  0  1  0
>       ...
> 
> Matrix: Whether a user purchased an item or not
```

I converted the purchases dataset to `scipy.coo_matrix` and thought that I have to then do `tocsr()` to do the normalization and similarities calculations between products, but found out that when we transform a `coo_matrix` to `csr_matrix` it sums the duplicates (which I don't want to happen, I only want 1 and 0 in my matrix).

Is there a way to get around that and calculate cosine similarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a `csr_matrix` supports item indexing you can use the following one liner to convert everything larger than one to one

```
X[X > 1] = 1
```